# Runtime.exec(String) limiting String

Tags: java

I'm trying to use the Java function `Runetime.exec(String)` to run a program in the startup folder of a windows 7 computer like so:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(runner.getPath() + "\\run.bat");
```

And when I run this I get an error saying the command cannot be run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ""C:\Users\ly
ndsey\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start": CreateProcess error=2, The syste
m cannot find the file specified
```

As you can see, the file name is cut off at the "\Windows\Start" when it should continue to "\Windows\Startup\run.bat".. Is there an alternative I can use?

Comment: Are you sure it's `Startup` and not `Start up`?

Comment: what's runner? what type is it?

Comment: Would you provide us the "runner" class implementation ? Here lie your problem, but we can't investigate it ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun I'm pretty sure it's in fact "Start Menu\Programs\Startup".

Comment: runner is just a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering `runner` as a File instance, this should work.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(runner, "run.bat"));
```

It uses `Desktop` class instead of `Runtime`, so you don't have to convert your `File` (runner) to its `String` representation (which is error prone). Runner is now used 'as is' as the parent directory of the "run.bat" you want to execute.

Other advantage of `Desktop` class : you can now open any file you want.

Comment: I'm going to ignore the "Don't say thanks" in the comments box, thank you very much :) Simple and works great.

Comment: Consider avoiding the usage of String or primitive types when you are actually handling something else (a file in this case) : this will save you a lot of time :D 
You're welcome

Comment: Downside: more indirect therefore less reliable when executing actual commands. Plus, no argument passing. I'd say it just about makes it for this exact invocation. It is not a general replacement for exec.

Comment: I wonder, Shaun, if you are aware that this relies on user-configured file association. It may just as well end up opening the .bat file in Notepad.

Answer (score 1):

as i can see from the error you give, and i hope it's a copy past, you string `runner.getPath()` for some reason start and end with "\"" which make the whole path invalid. check that and remove it if needed

if you have the file already and you just need it's path you can use

```
runner.getAbsolutePath()
```

also, if runner is a file, `getPath` will give you the file path including the path, so your code will surely won't work. instead use:

```
String path = runner.getPath();
path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("\\")) + "\\run.bat";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path);
```

Comment: @downvoter please leave a comment, i'll delete the post if it's invalid, but tell me why is it not true

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I'll explain: you are right that he has the extra quote, and that will be a problem later on, but it is not the immediate cause of the current error. Have an upvote from me for bringing up a valid point :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use `ProcessBuilder`. I feel `ProcessBuilder` is more safe than `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

```
    String[] command = {"CMD", "/C", "dir"};
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( command );
    //set up your work directory if needed
    pb.directory(new File("c:\\path"));

    Process process = pb.start();
```

Comment: Can you explain that first line please? This answer looks the most promising.

Comment: First line is array of commands you want to execute. On running this code it will open cmd and show you directory in path it executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid the `exec(String)` method, which attempts to parse the entire string into command + arguments. The safe option is [`exec(String[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29), which presupposes the first array element is the command and the rest are arguments.

So, writing

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec(new String[] { yourCommandString })
```

is a surefire way of getting the right message across.

Comment: According to javadoc, exec (new String[]{}) and exec (String) result in the same call to exec (String, String[],File) :(

Comment: @Olivier, both end up calling `exec(String[],String[],File)`. The `exec(String)` version creates an array by splitting on whitespace.